# Performance of MutationObserver to detect nodes in entire DOM

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers

I'm interested in using `MutationObserver` to detect if a certain HTML element is added anywhere in an HTML page. For example's sake, I'll say that I want to detect if any `<li>`'s are added anywhere in the DOM.

All the `MutationObserver` examples I've seen so far only detect if a node is added to a particular container. For example:

some HTML

```
<body>

  ...

  <ul id='my-list'></ul>

  ...

</body>
```

`MutationObserver` definition

```
var container = document.querySelector('ul#my-list');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  // Do something here
});

observer.observe(container, {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributeOldValue: true,
  characterDataOldValue: true
});
```

So in this example, the `MutationObserver` is setup to watch a very certain container (`ul#my-list`) to see if any `<li>`'s are appended to it.

Is it a problem if I wanted to be **less specific**, and watch for `<li>`'s over the entire HTML body like this:

```
var container = document.querySelector('body');
```

I know it works in the basic examples I've setup for myself... But is it not advised to do this? Is this going to result in poor performance? And if so, how would I detect and measure that performance issue?

I figured maybe there was a reason that all the `MutationObserver` examples are so specific with their targeted container... but I'm not sure.

Comment: Performance issues are specific to a given scenario. If your entire document only has a few simple elements I'm certain you won't have any issues. If you fear having performance issues, profile!

Comment: I have used plenty of `MutationObserver`s and had them recursively watch the entire DOM. I've personally never had a problem with performance.

Comment: The primary reason for the introduction of MutationObservers and the deprecation of MutationEvents is because MutationObservers are much faster because they aggregate changes together. We also use MutationObservers with `subtree: true` on large documents and it has never been an issue.

Comment: Why are you observing changes in attributes and character data? You say so yourself -- you want to observe possible additions of `li` elements? If something is a candidate for sub-optimal performance, I'd say asking for more events than you need, is that.

Comment: As an example, Boomerang.js (https://github.com/akamai/boomerang), the web performance monitoring lib, is using a `MutationObserver` on the whole document to measure SPAs page load time.

Comment: If you just want to detect if any <li>'s are added anywhere in the DOM.
You don't need  `attributes: true, characterData: true, attributeOldValue: true, characterDataOldValue: true`

Answer (score 351, accepted):

### This answer primarily applies to big and complex pages.

If attached before page load/render, an unoptimized MutationObserver callback can add a few seconds to page load time (say, 5 sec to 7 sec) if the page is big and complex ([1](https://github.com/RequestPolicy/requestpolicy/compare/dev-1.0...RequestPolicyContinued:dev-1.0), [2](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)). The callback is executed as a microtask that blocks further processing of DOM and can be fired hundreds or a thousand of times per second on a complex page. Most of the examples and existing libraries don't account for such scenarios and offer good-looking, easy to use, but potentially slow JS code.

0. Always use the [devtools profiler](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/js-execution?hl=en) and try to make your observer callback consume less than 1% of overall CPU time consumed during page load.
1. Avoid triggerring [forced synchronous layout](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/) by accessing offsetTop and similar properties
2. Avoid using complex DOM frameworks/libraries like jQuery, prefer native DOM stuff
3. When observing attributes, use `attributeFilter: ['attr1', 'attr2']` option in `.observe()`.
4. Whenever possible observe direct parents nonrecursively (`subtree: false`).
   For example, it makes sense to wait for the parent element by observing `document` recursively, disconnect the observer on success, attach a new nonrecursive one on this container element.
5. When waiting for just one element with an `id` attribute, use the insanely fast `getElementById` *instead* of enumerating the `mutations` array (it may have thousands of entries): [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38882022).
6. In case the desired element is relatively rare on the page (e.g. `iframe` or `object`) use the live HTMLCollection returned by `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` and recheck them all *instead* of enumerating the `mutations` if it has more than 100 elements, for example.
7. Avoid using `querySelector` and especially the extremely slow `querySelectorAll`.
8. If `querySelectorAll` is absolutely unavoidable inside MutationObserver callback, first perform a `querySelector` check, and if successful, proceed with `querySelectorAll`. On the average such combo will be a lot faster.
9. If targeting pre-2018 Chrome/ium, don't use the built-in Array methods like forEach, filter, etc. that require callbacks because in Chrome's V8 these functions have always been expensive to invoke compared to the classic `for (var i=0 ....)` loop (10-100 times slower), and MutationObserver callback may report thousands of nodes on complex modern pages.

- The alternative functional enumeration backed by lodash or similar fast library is okay even in older browsers.
- As of 2018 Chrome/ium is inlining the standard array built-in methods.

8. If targeting pre-2019 browsers, don't use [the slow ES2015 loops](https://kpdecker.github.io/six-speed/) like `for (let v of something)` inside MutationObserver callback unless you transpile so that the resultant code runs as fast as the classic `for` loop.
9. If the goal is to alter how page looks and you have a reliable and fast method of telling that elements being added are outside of the visible portion of the page, disconnect the observer and schedule an entire page rechecking&reprocessing via `setTimeout(fn, 0)`: it will be executed when the initial burst of parsing/layouting activity is finished and the engine can "breathe" which could take even a second. Then you can inconspicuously process the page in chunks using requestAnimationFrame, for example.
10. If processing is complex and/or takes a lot of time, it may lead to very long paint frames, unresponsiveness/jank, so in this case you can use *debounce* or a similar technique e.g. accumulate mutations in an outer array and schedule a run via setTimeout / requestIdleCallback / requestAnimationFrame:

    ```js
    const queue = [];
    const mo = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      if (!queue.length) requestAnimationFrame(process);
      queue.push(mutations);
    });
    function process() {
      for (const mutations of queue) {
        // ..........
      }
      queue.length = 0;
    }
    ```

    Note that requestAnimationFrame fires only when the page is (or becomes) visible.

## Back to the question:

> watch a very certain container `ul#my-list` to see if any `<li>` are appended to it.

Since `li` is a direct child, and we look for added nodes, *the only option needed* is `childList: true` (see advice #2 above).

```
new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    // Do something here

    // Stop observing if needed:
    observer.disconnect();
}).observe(document.querySelector('ul#my-list'), {childList: true});
```

Comment: Apparently I can't award a bounty immediately but I'm giving this answer a 50 point bounty because I find the live DOM collection trick for watching rare elements clever! Good answer!

Comment: Also, you might want to update the list - for example `for... of` is as fast as a regular for loop now in V8 :]

Comment: Yes, it's finally slower by just 10% or even less in recent versions of Chrome.

Comment: There was an intermediate stage where it was converted to a regular loop (with a counter) but apparently it was replaced to its own IR instruction in https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/06ee127b75726f9ee541aab10f6aecfe4d96675a - pretty cool stuff! In any case, for...of vs for shouldn't matter much here (worth mentioning that this optimization is for arrays - so the advice still holds some merit for NodeLists)

Comment: What's the point of debouncing the mutation observer? I thought it already does that natively by collecting mutations in an array and then calling the callback only once. See also [this new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65554806/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi, it's for the case when processing is complex and takes a lot of time. MutationObserver runs in a microtask queue so multiple callbacks may still reside in one task, which can lead to very long paint frames and jank.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am figuring this stuff out, but I just noticed that when I register an observer for a parent object first and then proceed to register another one later for a child, I do not get the events on the child. This has led me to believe that my best strategy is simply to register one on body or higher if possible and then detect the desired element and trigger my own event/listener myself. however, I wonder if this is really the best. I am confused why I am unable to observe a child if a parent is already observed. Since either childList or characterData has to be true I see no simple ...

Comment: @mmm, some sites may swap the entire container with the new rendered element high up in the tree so indeed you won't be able to use this optimization in such cases. If you want to discuss this further, please open a new question with an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm Here is a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69426920/javascript-mutationobserver-observing-a-child-element-after-observing-a-parent

Comment: This is an incredible explanation. You should follow your 5th point in your final answer, however :) 
`document.getElementById('my-list')` instead of `document.querySelector('ul#my-list')`

Comment: @jfudman, this answer is about the callback of the observer because it may (theoretically) run thousands of times. Finding the parent in this example is a one-time deal so there's no need to optimize it unless someone observes hundreds of different parents creating hundreds of observers.

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer as the question specifically states that he does _not_ want to observer a specific element but rather be _less specific_ and observe the whole body element?

Comment: Unbelievable answer, what a champion.

Comment: `const mo = new MutationObserver(async mutations => {
   // ...
});` is also a good approach to avoid DOM changing during mutation observer callback.