# Observe mutations on a target node that doesn't exist yet

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

Is it possible to observer mutations on a DOM node that doesn't exist yet?

**Example:**

My app creates a div at some point: `<div id="message" data-message-content="foo" data-message-type="bar" />`.

I want to watch for the creation & change of this div.

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  // Some code to handle the mutation.
});

mutationObserver.observe(
    document.querySelector('#message'),
        { 
            attributes: true, 
            subtree: true, 
            childList: true, 
            characterData: false 
        }
    );
);
```

Right now this returns an **error** since `#message` is null (the div hasn't been created yet).

`Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

An obvious solution is to watch the `body` and check if any of the mutations are the creation of `div#Message`, but this seems like a bad idea / or possibly bad for performance.

Comment: How are you creating the element? Can't you add this in the same method  that creates it so it is actually created then?

Comment: Unfortunately no - this is for a Google Chrome plugin.  Plugins have a few annoying scope restrictions. Basically this observer exists in an entirely different scope than the window / functions that create the div.

Comment: The obvious solution is the only one, unless the site emits some kind of event prior to adding that node.

Comment: `Refer this answer how I fixed it` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212681/how-to-add-event-listener-for-onclick-popup-in-javascript

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Only an existing node can be observed.

You can use `document.getElementById()` in MutationObserver callback, it's super fast compared to enumeration of all mutated nodes (see also [Performance of MutationObserver](/a/39332340)).

```
function waitForAddedNode(params, callback) {
    new MutationObserver(mutations => {
        var el = document.getElementById(params.id);
        if (el) {
            this.disconnect();
            callback(el);
        }
    }).observe(params.parent || document, {
        subtree: !!params.recursive || !params.parent,
        childList: true,
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
waitForAddedNode({
    id: 'message',
    //parent: document.querySelector('.container'),
    recursive: true,
}, el => {
    console.log(el);
});
```

Comment: An ingenious approach as you're not relying on the mutations properties (where I have had difficulty) but just checking the required element exists each time. A bit like polling with a timeout. Relies on element having an id though...