# How to check if my Bokeh Server Application is completely loaded and rendered?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, electron, bokeh

I would like to integrate my Bokeh Server Application in Electron. So what I did is to run bokeh server using `python-shell` like this

```javascript
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 700,
    show: false,
})

var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonPath: 'python3',
    pythonOptions: ['-m'],
    scriptPath: '',
    args: ['serve','bokeh_project/']
};

PythonShell.run('bokeh', options, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('results: %j', results);
});

mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:5006');

mainWindow.once('did-finish-load', () => {
    mainWindow.show()
})
```

The problem here is that the window never pops up because electron does not detect the server as loaded.

Comment: You are welcome @Joris :) I have added an "Update 4" with an extra possible solution. Maybe you have already checked that on the other question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Bokeh developer](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4272#issuecomment-679487409) (I didn't try it yet):

> Noting that `DocumentReady` was added in 2.2 but currently only for Bokeh server apps, e.g.
>
> ```
> curdoc().on_event(DocumentReady, ...)
> ```
>
> We would like to add for `CustomJS` but this will be tricky due to implicit documents, might require requiring explicit document manipulation (to have a target doc to call js_on_event on)

I have also found a bunch of workarounds.

### Workaround 1

So I had to add this `setTimeout` as a workaround. If I do not use this the page would be stuck forever.

```javascript
setTimeout(function () {
    mainWindow.show();
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:5006');
}, 3000);
```

### Workaround 2

It checks if the bokeh port is still closed. But the elements may be not loaded and completely loaded

```javascript
var portscanner = require('portscanner')
var _checkServerStatus = setInterval(function() {
  portscanner.checkPortStatus(5006, '127.0.0.1', function(error, status) {
    if (status == 'open') {  // status = 'open' or 'close'
        clearInterval(_checkServerStatus);
        console.log('Server running');
        mainWindow.loadURL(bokehUrl); 
    }
  });
}, 100);
```

### Workaround 3

Finally I found another workaround to check if all the elements are completely rendered. The answer is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915626/how-to-override-methods-on-bokeh-how-to-check-if-all-the-elements-are-already-r):

```javascript
oldLog = console.log;
console.log = function (message) {
    if(message.localeCompare('Bokeh items were rendered successfully') == 0){
        window.top.postMessage('show-bokeh-iframe', '*')
        console.log = oldLog;
    }
    oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

### Workaround 4

There is a [GH issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4272) where where the writer ask for calling a callback when bokeh is completely loaded and rendered. The user foobarbecue suggests to verify if the bokeh page is rendered with [**MutationObserver**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881301/observe-mutations-on-a-target-node-that-doesnt-exist-yet/38882022#38882022), but I have never used it.