# How to render a CheckboxGroup (or any other element) in a custom way?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, templates, bokeh

Bokeh renders the checkboxes like this

```
<div class="bk-bs-checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="0">
        Label text
    </label>
</div>
```

But I would like to select the label depending on the input state `:focus`, `:disabled`, `:checked`, ...

Since there is no CSS parent selector, what I could do to render the checkbox in a custom way? I would like to avoid JavaScript. If the checkbox is rendered as the following code it would be easier to customize:

```
<div class="bk-bs-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="0">
    <label>
        Label text
    </label>
</div>
```

And I could this CSS code to select the label depending the checkbox state:

```
.bk-bs-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label::after {
    background-color: red,
}
```

This is just an example to show one case of use.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? Actually I am looking for some mechanism in bokeh to inherit the template that renders that object in order to change it with my custom template.

Comment: You can only do this using Javascript

Comment: @gerard OK, actually what I was asking is if there is some mechanism in bokeh to inherit the template that renders that object in order to change it with my custom template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I have found a workaround that is not very clean, but it works. Basically I have hidden the original element and I have created my own customised control. I have used JavaScript as @Gerard suggested.

1. First I need to wait until Bokeh Server is loaded. All the elements must be already rendered. So I have applied some workaround from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54110237/4891717)
2. Then I have hidden the original element generated by bokeh using the python attribute `css_classes` and the CSS tyle `display: none;`
3. I have created the element by JavaScript (actually I have enabled jQuery). This can be done with bokeh templates as well. In my case I found it more convenient like this. Then I have added the element before the original one.

   ```javascript
   var new_cb = $('<div>', {
       class: 'abc-checkbox abc-checkbox-primary',
   });
   new_cb.append(
       $('<input>', {
           id: 'id_new_cb',
           type: 'checkbox'
       })
   );
   new_cb.append(
       $('<label>', {
           for: 'id_new_cb',
           text: 'Custom element'
       })
   );
   $('.original_cb').before(new_cb);
   ```
4. Finally I have added an event to trigger the event on the original hidden element:

   ```javascript
   $('#id_new_cb').change(function() {
       if(this.checked) {
           $('.original_cb input').click();
       } else {
           $('.original_cb input').click();
       }
   });
   ```

Something similar can be done with the rest of the elements. This is useful if you just want to change a couple of elements. If not this will become kind of cumbersome.