# How to add event Listener for onclick PopUp In Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Consider there is some hyperlink tag that makes the API call to backend.

**Example:**

```
<a  href="/get/contact-info/" id="ember107" >Contact info </a>
```

After the backend API call completed it will trigger/open a popup in that page.

**Popup data: (Sample one div data)**

```
<div id="ember"> <h1 id="pv-contact-info"> Contact Name</h1></div>
```

My objective is to extract data from this popup (above tag). Lets say Contact Name from h1 tag.

**what I tried so far:**

```
let atag = document.getElementById("ember107");
atag.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    document.getElementById("pv-contact-info").innerText; // getting from popup h1 tag
});
atag.click(); // explicit click
```

**The Problem I faced** is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null` when this statement is executed `document.getElementById("pv-contact-info").innerText;`

I know the problem is popup content was not loaded completely that's why this code  `document.getElementById("pv-contact-info")` returning null.

**My Question is** whether there is any listener function to check Popup content is loaded
completely or we can do this in another approach. Most preferable using browser support /vanilla javascript rather than library.

Comment: `document.getElementById("pv-contact-info").innerText;`  does actually not do anything

Comment: If you have more than one link with id="ember107" you code will also fail. I am guessing you will need delegation but your code is not elaborate enough for me to be sure

Comment: How is the `atag` generated? Where do you call your JS?

Comment: Well does the modal have events for when it is loaded? Most libraries do.

Comment: @mplungjan for the sake of example I mentioned this single tag with id. My objective is to fetch the data from the pop up. Once it is loaded completely. How can I know whether it is loaded?

Comment: @epascarello when I  do the explicit click <a> it will trigger the event. For the sake of data extraction I'm doing this click.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava consider it is available in browser document object.

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 What I am saying is a lot of modal libraries have an event that tells you when the dialog is shown. EG bootstrap has `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { })`. Check to see if your library you are using has events on modals.

Comment: @epascarello sorry I didn't mention this in my question , I need to achieve this in vanilla javascript.

Comment: So as the other answer states, mutation observer or you poll until element exists.

Comment: @epascarello is it possible to do in eventlistner by adding another addEventListerner in that.

Comment: @epascarello or else can we achieve in promise or async/await??

Comment: You can, but it is still going be a timeout/interval inside the promise code or mutation observer

Comment: @epascarello could you elaborate? My assumption is whether I await for popup click event it won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a MutationObserver to watch for changes to the DOM on the page. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

If you need to stay compatible with older browsers use your click event to trigger your own manual watcher. Something like:

```js
var interval_id = false;
function lookForPopup(){
    if(interval_id){
        clearInterval(interval_id);
    }else{
        interval_id = setInterval(function(){
            var popup = document.getElementById('some-id');
            if(popup){
                // do something

                clearInterval(interval_id);
            }
        },1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or likely just delegate

Comment: assuming the ajax call takes some time a delegated listener would still need to wait for the new element to be created. I'm assuming OP can't change the ajax success function else wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Sorry as per my requirement I should not go for setTimeOut because if an API takes more time this may break in worstcases.

Comment: Well it is not a timeout, it is an interval that keeps checking....

Answer (score 0):

As @Gavin already suggested to use `MutationObserver` I like to elaborate a little bit.

**How I fixed this issue using `MutationObserver`.**

```
MutationObserver has an ability to watch for changes being made to the DOM tree.
 I mention the code below how it fixed my issue/requirement.


 // selecting the href by id and triggering a click event.
 let hrefDoc = document.getElementById("ember");
 divDoc.click();


let m = new MutationObserver(() => {
  let divDoc = document.getElementById("ember");
    new MutationObserver( () => {
          // Finally Extracting the required data
          console.log(document.getElementById("pv-contact-info").innerText);
        }
      }).observe(divDoc || document,observerOptions);
  });
m.observe(hrefDoc,observerOptions);
```

As you can see above I added another child MutationObserver to observe the divDoc element. That is because it is when the `hrefDoc` click event the parent `MutationObserver` callback is called with some observeroptions. But in that case I could not get my `<div id="ember">` Mutation Node.

That's the reason I added another this statement `let divDoc = document.getElementById("ember");` and waiting for this targetNode in the child `MutationObserver`. Finally I extracted the data from this tag `<h1 id="pv-contact-info">`