# How to trigger a JS function when the content of a page changes

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm writing a script to be triggered every time the page loads more content, or as I understand, child nodes are added to the html of the page. I used to mutation observer to observe the div named `main` in the page. The idea is when scrolled to the bottom, the page will load new content, hence trigger my function. But somehow my function doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me fix this? The website I'm trying to manipulate is the [9GAG](https://9gag.com) website. Here's my code:

```
function adbut(){
console.log("hd");}

const observerOptions = {
  childList: true,

};

    const mainid = document.querySelector("#main");
    const observer = new MutationObserver(adbut);
observer.observe(mainid, observerOptions);
```

There's an answered question about observing a DOM that doesn't exist yet. It's different from what I'm trying to do because I'm trying to observe an existing `div` with the id `main`. The element exists and the code above return no error but somehow the function isn't triggered when more content is loaded. That answered question is located here: [observe node that doesn't exist yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881301/observe-mutations-on-a-target-node-that-doesnt-exist-yet)

Comment: Hi Randy. This question was closed because you can do this via mutationObserver - you just need to study/play-with it and figure out how it works.  It's a bit of a time investment, but you will use it again and again. There are other methods to do this also, but mutationObserver is the best. If you want a different approach, please edit your question to request non-mutationObserver answers and ask that this question be re-opened - but really, mutationObserver is what you should learn. And you will learn it by spending a few hours playing with it.

Comment: @cssyphus MutationObserver is what OP is already using.

Comment: @cssyphus I've used it already and it didn't work. That's why I posted this question

Comment: Yes, I realize you are already using MO. And actually, MO will work - that is why wOxxOm closed the question - but it can be tricky to implement, especially the first time you use it. However, since the question is now closed (i.e. No new answers allowed, argh!), your only recourse is to (a) ask another, slightly different, question for the same problem, or (b) Edit this question and clearly state that you do not want a mutationObserver answer (explain why) and ask for this question to be re-opened.  I would be happy to try to answer it tomorrow.

Comment: @cssyphus the problem isn't with watching an element that doesn't exist yet. #main exists.

Comment: Yes, I realize that - it is the child nodes that do not yet exist, right? MO can watch for that. But [here is another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53161629) that you might find more helpful for what you are doing.