# How capture all files transfert (like "network" panel in dev mode)

Tags: javascript, performance, tampermonkey, transfer, dev-mode

I have a little problem, I use the `performance.getEntriesByType("resource")` to listen all files transfert, but I monitor with the "Network" panel of Chrome (in dev mode) and some files is miss.

In the "Network" panel, the type miss is "media"; a m4a file exactly. This file is used in a webplayer of a page.

I have tried to monitor with another; `performance.getEntries()` and nothing about the requested file.

My need is monitoring the file network usage and report all on a local log (I use TamperMonkey, for script). For now, I see types; img, fetch, xmlhttprequest and script correctly. Some times I can catch "audio" or "video", but not each time. The dev network tab not have this problem.

(sorry for my poor English, I'm better for read)

Comment: It's either a bug in the browser or an intended behavior (maybe because those files are streamed). If the page is using XMLHttpRequest/fetch to get that m4a you can install a hook ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57816391)).

Comment: Thank about this page, but after test, I only got with this code the xmlhttprequest, all other files is ignored. I'm looking to catch media type file.

Comment: Can't you combine both results?

Comment: I have made the current job with other way, for this project is ok. But why performance can catch everything excepted media (or with difficulty) ? But dev tabs can do this.