# Find element on the page after fetch | JS

Tags: javascript, dom, fetch

How to declare const and find element on the page, that was dynamically rendered after fetch?

Let's say I have navigation with first element hard coded in html and the rest dynamically rendered after fetch.

If I declare it at the beginning of the script:

```
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('#nav li');
```

it only finds the first one (hard coded). I understand why this is happening, but I'm not sure what to do with this. I need all of navItems in other functions and it's not working.

If I declare it in the last `then` of the fetch function. It works, but I'm not sure it's a correct way. It doesn't look 'pretty'.

Comment: It's is a right way. Another way is to "convert" it to function `const navItems = () => document.querySelectorAll('#nav li');` so when you need it, instead of `navItems` you call `navItems()`.

Comment: Please let us know WHY and for WHAT you want to find them all. I was guessing you need to click the LIs and need to assign event handlers. this question is a bit like an X/Y problem until you let us know what you were planning with the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could emit a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) at the end of your fetch (in the `then` clause) or you could use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to check for changes in the DOM in a specific subtree (your nav, for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign event handlers to your new LIs, you need to [delegate](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

```
document.querySelector('#nav').addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName==="LI") {
    console.log(tgt.textContent;
  }
  const navItems = tgt.querySelectorAll("li");
  console.log(navItems.length)
})
```

that will work regardless of WHEN you insert the LIs

Comment: Yes but that code will run every time you click a nav element which isn't really ideal.

Comment: That VERY MUCH depends on what OP wants. If he wants to click any new LI this IS the way to do it

Comment: He specified he wants to select all the nav elements after a fetch, so I believe it would be better to just wait for that fetch to finish and do what you have to do, instead of having some logic repeating itself indefinetly.

Comment: There is nothing here repeating indefinitely. Why would this logic repeat itself? It is ONE event listener that will react to ONE click at a time and not repeat anything.

Comment: A mutation observer is running indefinitely until you stop it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659567/performance-of-mutationobserver-to-detect-nodes-in-entire-dom/39332340

Comment: The code inside the event listener will be triggered every time there is a click event, we can agree on that. If you want to unsubscribe the event, you need a way to know if the dynamic elements have been created, and so you might as well just use a more direct method of doing just that, and trigger your code that one time and not on every click.

Comment: Of course, but you detect the creation of the new elements the moment they are created, do your thing and unsubscribe. It's more reliable.

Comment: The code inside the event listener will execute when a click occurs inside the nav container. That is VERY likely what we need.

Comment: In no way does OP specify that the behaviour needs to be retriggered on click, OP just wants to know when the dynamic elements are loaded so that he can select them. We can agree to disagree haha

Comment: We have no idea WHY he wants to select them. Perhaps he wants to select them so he can add the event listener to them all again and again

Comment: Exactly, we don't know why, you make assumptions that really don't apply to what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You could access that element you dynamically added with [event delegation](https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/part-4-what-is-event-delegation-in-javascript-f5c8c0de2983). As an example let's say you want to add an event listener to that element:

First, add a class 'example' to it.
Then fire off `func` only when an element with that class is clicked on.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', func);

const func = (e) => {
  if (e.target.className === 'example') {
    console.log('element accessed!'};
}
```

Not saying that's the most elegant or pretty way to go, but it is definitely an option in such cases.

Comment: I’m happy it did!